# How to resize NSTextView

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, resize, frame, nstextview

I want to resize `NSTextView` accordingly to it's content. Initially its height equals one line height and if there's more then one line of text, I want to resize it to three line height.

The problem is TextContainer size is not affected when I resize text view.
Here is screenshot to better illustrate the problem.
 Text view has red background color to distinguish from scroll view, and definitely its size changed. As you can see, part of the text that is on the second line is not displayed fully as if text container were smaller than text view

[image: NSTextView screenshot]
**Here is code I use for resizing:**

```
-(void)unfold {

  NSScrollView *scrollView = (NSScrollView *)self.superview.superview;

  NSRect scrollFrame = scrollView.frame;
  NSRect textFrame = self.frame;

  scrollFrame.size.height=62;
  scrollFrame.origin.y-=40;
  textFrame.size.height=60;

  self.superview.superview.frame = scrollFrame;
  self.frame=textFrame;

}
```

I also tried to play around with text container setHeightTracksTextView or changing its size but it wouldn't work.

Comment: Did you try to use AutoLayout?

Comment: @Astoria, absolutely right. Disabling AutoLayout helped with that issue.